# Save and restore fragment when activity is popped from back stack

Tags: android

How can I save a Fragment's state when a user presses the back button, and then restore it the next time I load the fragment? I tried `onSaveInstanceState`, but it doesn't get called when I hit back, and the `Bundle` passed into `onCreate` is `null`.

For context, I have a title Activity which starts a new game Activity when the user presses a button (e.g., "New game"). The second (game) activity loads an XML layout in `onCreate` which consists of the custom `Fragment`. When the user presses the back button, I want to return to the title Activity, but provide a "resume game" button. To do so, I need to save some custom state data for the Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default onSaveInstanceState() call doesn't occur when user press Back

> If the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the stack and >destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is resumed. When an activity is destroyed, the >system does not retain the activity's state.

So the way you can do it seems to be: (1) Override activity's onBackPressed() with your own implementation where you (2) Save fragment instance. Take a look at the FragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState() - i believe that this is what you need